# I am really not sure of what カンナ is saying in this text

Tags: translation

[image]

So I am planning on buying a japanese 3ds to import Fire emblem IF. I am currently going through screenshots of the game (that aren't filled with spoilers) and translating them as 'warmup' before I get the real thing. But I am just not sure of what Kanna is saying here. Something about his mother being his maid?

Comment: Please explain precisely what you did not understand and include your own attempt. Otherwise, it is very likely that your question will be closed because we don't do translations.

Comment: Well it is primarily the last sentence. But i got it to something like "You see, today my mother is my maid", but I am 90% sure that this translation is wrong.

Comment: Ehh, it's 22:30 and I haven't gotten an ounce of sleep. I'm embarresed by that translation attempt.

Comment: Try to identify the subject, and notice the して（い）た after お手伝い

Answer (score 4):

Kanna is saying;
“Look, I’ve been assisting (helping chores of) my mother.” “お手伝いしていた” is a verb in past tense and the same with” 手伝っていた” - I was helping (someone). It‘s different from “お手伝い、” a noun meaning a housemaid.  I’m chuckling to find myself, an 83year old Japanese translating the script of Manga.